# How to get chart min and max values after Drag zooming in highChart chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

http://jsfiddle.net/leongaban/0zuxtdcg/

I could not find a "Drag zoom" type event in the HighChart docs that would tell me that the user has finished zooming into a specific range on the chart, then give me the new min and max values.

```
$(function () {
  $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=usdeur.json&callback=?', function (data) {

      $('#container').highcharts({
          chart: {
              zoomType: 'x'
          },
          title: {
              text: 'USD to EUR exchange rate over time'
          },
          subtitle: {
              text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                      'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' : 'Pinch the chart to zoom in'
          },
          xAxis: {
              type: 'datetime'
          },
          yAxis: {
              title: {
                  text: 'Exchange rate'
              }
          },
          legend: {
              enabled: false
          },
          plotOptions: {
              area: {
                  fillColor: {
                      linearGradient: {
                          x1: 0,
                          y1: 0,
                          x2: 0,
                          y2: 1
                      },
                      stops: [
                          [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                          [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                      ]
                  },
                  marker: {
                      radius: 2
                  },
                  lineWidth: 1,
                  states: {
                      hover: {
                          lineWidth: 1
                      }
                  },
                  threshold: null
              }
          },

          series: [{
              type: 'area',
              name: 'USD to EUR',
              data: data
          }]
      });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The zoom effects the extremes of the axis. You can use the [`setExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes) or [`afterSetExtremes`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes) events of the axis to catch this.

For example ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0zuxtdcg/2/)):

```
xAxis: {
    events: {
        setExtremes: function(e) {
            alert("Min: "+e.min+"\n"
                    +"Max: "+e.max);
        }
    }
}
```

The `e` object contains the min and max, while `this` in the function is the Axis object (which also has min and max). The minor difference between the two events is described in the API as:

> `afterSetExtremes` ... As opposed to the `setExtremes` event, this event fires after the final min and max values are computed and corrected for `minRange`.